# Не запускается Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, composer

Работал в Composer (среда на основе Eclipse), программа сама завершила работу и больше не запускается, отображается ошибка, что на скрине.

---

[image: скриншот ошибки]

---

Подскажите, что может быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Програма Composer чувствительна к установленой на компьютере версии Java.
Установка более старой версии помогает устранить эту проблему.
Желательо отключить обновления Java во избежания повторного инцидента.
Надо учесть что обновления надо отключиить для обоих версий(x32 и x64) если таковые установлены.

Comment: о святой интернет! спасибо огромущее за ваш комментарий!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас ошибка в INI файле (eclipse.ini) или для вашей программы он может называться по другому, но обязательно расположен в корневом каталоге вашей программы. Его содержимое видно на вашем скриншоте. Опция `-vm` и следующий за ней путь к Java должны находится в разных строках (не должны быть записаны в одной строке), например, должно быт так:

   ```
   -vm
   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
   ```
2. Вызывает сомнение сам путь к Java, этот должно быть где-то в `Program Files`. Скорее всего, вы установили ещё какую-то программу, которая прописала в PATH свою встроенную версию Java. Надо это исправить.

Исправьте PATH и вообще удалите опцию -vm из INI файла, автоматически должна подцепиться Java, установленная в системе по умолчанию. Если у вас такой нет, установите JDK с  сайта Oracle.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Пробрался в эту папку 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\'
там лежит 3 файла с разрешением .exe которые занимают 0 кб и ссылаються на фалы которые лежат в 'Program Files'.

Comment: При попытке их открыть появляеться окно ошибки с сообщением:
"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
the specified path does not exist.
Правка PATH не помогла, видимо какой то еще модуль ходит по старому адресу C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\.

Подсажите что за тип файла такой с разрешением exe но который выполняет функцию ярлыка. Нужно как то убрать ошибку. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Установите JDK с сайта Oracle, судя по всему вам нужна 32-битная версия. В PATH в самое начало добавьте путь к папке BIN установленной JDK. Проверьте - в командной строке наберите `java -version`, вы должны увидеть что запускается та версия java, которая у вас установлена и которая прописана в PATH. Если это не так, то у вас проблема с PATH - надо исправить. После этого удалить из INI файла вашего приложения опцию `-vm` и путь к Java, который прописан в этой опции. Если всё вышеописанное сделано правильно, ваше приложение должно заработать.